# How to get "today's local midnight expressed in UTC" using .NET core?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, time, .net-core

I am trying to get a timestamp for "Local midnight in UTC" using .NET Core.

I wrote this code:

```
var utcTimeStartLocalDay =
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(convertToLocalTimezone(DateTime.UtcNow).Date);
```

where

```
public DateTime ConvertToLocalTimezone(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Utc,TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("FLE Standard Time"));
}
```

So, the idea is to get Utc timestamp, convert it to local TZ, then take Date (that is, discard time part and effectively make a midnight timestamp)  and convert back to Utc - that should have given me local time.

However, it did not happen, as the result of the first expression is Utc midnight when printed.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wJIXve

What do I need to correct here to get as the answer the local midnight for the day expressed as UTC (something like 22:00 UTC previous day)?

Edit: just to clarify an unclearness in  the question: by "local" TZ I meant *known* local timezone (found in the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that you are definitely using local time, I would use this code:

```
DateTime localMidnight = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now.Date, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

Then simply use `.ToUniversalTime()` to get the UTC date:

```
DateTime localMidnightUtc = localMidnight.ToUniversalTime();
```

Here's a working example:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime localMidnight = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now.Date, DateTimeKind.Local);
    DateTime localMidnightUtc = localMidnight.ToUniversalTime();

    Console.WriteLine($"localMidnight:    {localMidnight}");
    Console.WriteLine($"localMidnightUTC: {localMidnightUtc}");
}

// Output:
// localMidnight:    29.01.2020 00:00:00
// localMidnightUTC: 28.01.2020 23:00:00
```

(And now you know which timezone I'm in ;)

Comment: I also experimented and came to:https://dotnetfiddle.net/pu9HUU - the same idea but converting explicitly using stated time zone.

Comment: var date = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var dateTimeUnspec = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTimeUnspec, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Helsinki"));  (caveat: assuming that we are still in the same day when using UtcNow instead of Now).

Comment: @GTHvidsten - The `Kind` coming from `DateTime.Now` is already `DateTimeKind.Local` (always), so it's not necessary to specify it again.  (It doesn't hurt, just extraneous).

Comment: @AskarIbragimov - The code you just dropped in comments is fine (assuming you're running on Linux/OSX, and not Windows).  However it seems you asked to different questions (one about local time, one about a specific time zone) and are attempting to answer one yourself (which you could do as an answer rather than a comment).  In the future, it would be best to ask one question at a time.  Thanks.

Comment: Do keep in mind though that when you use `SpecifyKind`, you're throwing out an previously set kind.  So you must know ahead of time that the value provided is indeed in the given time zone.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint thanks for the feedback, indeed my problem is Local-agnostic (or rather, I try to make it so). However I did not want to amend the already answered question so I like to point out that I have accepted the answer to what I asked :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```cs
var result = DateTime.Now.Date.ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: True. You could make it more compact.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner is the same as .NET Framework:

```
DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u") gave me 2020-01-29 00:00:00Z

Comment: Hmm, not sure why unless you're ACTUALLY IN GMT.  I'm in US Central Time and that same statement yields `2020-01-29 06:00:00Z` under .NET Core 3.1